# QPainter, assigning different colors to text parts

Tags: c++, qt, colors, qpainter

I have the below code to display some text via `QPainter`

```
QPainter painter(this);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
painter.setPen(QColor(10, 10, 10, 255)); // text color
painter.fillRect(QRect(10, 10, 200, 100), QColor(100, 100, 100, 120)); //rectangular color
painter.setFont(font);
painter.drawText(20, 20,  "1 2 3 4");
```

I want to display each part of the text via different color, e.g. `1` in black, `2` in white, `3` in blue, and `4` in red. All the text should be in the same line. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any Qt class/func that does this work for you, so you can just do it yourself:

```
QPainter painter(this);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
painter.fillRect(QRect(10, 10, 200, 100), QColor(100, 100, 100, 120)); //rectangular color


QColor  colors [ 3 ]        = { QColor(255, 0, 0, 255), QColor(0, 255, 0, 255), QColor(0, 0, 255, 255) };
QString texts [ 3 ]         = { "1", "2", "3" };
QFontMetrics fontmetrics    ( painter.font () );
int     y                   = 20,
        x                   = 20;

for ( int i = 0; i < 3; ++ i )
{
    painter.setPen ( colors [ i ] );
    painter.drawText ( x, y, texts [ i ] );

    x += fontmetrics.width ( texts [ i ] );
}
```

Above code is using `QFontMetrics` to calculate the length in pixels of the inserted text, and then adds it to `x` for the next string.

Comment: thanks, it works fine, but how do you add the spacing?

Comment: Just change the strings. For example to `QString texts [ 3 ] = { "1 ", "2 ", "3 " };`. Or many other ways. It's up to what makes most sense in your actual code.

Comment: The "alternative" way is using Qt's rich text classes (QTextDocument, QTextLine, QTextLayout) to lay out a line with multiple formats and draw it.

Comment: @peppe rich texts classes seemed overkill to me for the scope of his question. +1 tho for mentioning them.